# Shiny if statement on conditional inputs

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, conditional-statements, r-markdown

I have created a series of conditional panels in the UI that make available some additional inputs. I want now to check if the inputs have been accessed or not and then return a value accordingly.

To do so I wrote the following code in Rmarkdown:

```
{R, include=FALSE, results=}

legindex<- (
if(isTruthy(input$leg2price)){return("Leg 1:")}
else if (isTruthy(input$leg3price)){return(c("Leg 1:","Leg 2:"))}
else if (isTruthy(input$leg4price)){return(c("Leg 1:","Leg 2:","Leg 3:"))}
else {return(c("Leg 1:","Leg 2:","Leg 3:","Leg 4:"))})
```

You can test it with the following R code:

```
library(shiny) 

ui <- fluidPage(
SelectInput("strategy", "Strategy:", choices = list("DIVIDEND FUTURE SPREAD","STRANGLE","BUTTERFLY","STRADDLE SWAP")),

conditionalPanel(
           
        
        condition = "input.strategy == 'DIVIDEND FUTURE SPREAD'||input.strategy == 'STRANGLE',
            
     
          
          div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg1position", "Leg 1 position:", choices = list("Buy", "Sell"))),
          div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg1type", "Leg 1 type:", choices = list("Call", "Put", "Future"))),
          div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg1price", "Leg 1 price",value = "")),
          div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg1strike", "Leg 1 strike",value = "")),
          div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg1exp", "Leg 1 exp",value = "")),
          div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg1ratio", "Leg 1 ratio",value = "")),
          
                  
          br(),
          
          div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg2position", "Leg 2 position:", choices = list("Buy", "Sell"))),
          div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg2type", "Leg 2 type:", choices = list("Call", "Put", "Future"))),
          div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg2price","Leg 2 price", value ="")),  
          div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg2strike", "Leg 2 strike",value = "")),
          div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg2exp", "Leg 2 exp",value = "")),
          div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg2ratio", "Leg 2 ratio",value = "")),
        
          br(),
          
          
          div(HTML("<br>")),br(),
          ),
      

      
      conditionalPanel(
        
        
        condition = "input.strategy == 'BUTTERFLY'",
        
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg1position", "Leg 1 position:", choices = list("Buy", "Sell"))),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg1type", "Leg 1 type:", choices = list("Call", "Put", "Future"))),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg1price", "Leg 1 price",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg1strike", "Leg 1 strike",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg1exp", "Leg 1 exp",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg1ratio", "Leg 1 ratio",value = "")),
        
        br(),
        
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg2position", "Leg 2 position:", choices = list("Buy", "Sell"))),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg2type", "Leg 2 type:", choices = list("Call", "Put", "Future"))),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg2price","Leg 2 price", value ="")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg2strike", "Leg 2 strike",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg2exp", "Leg 2 exp",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg2ratio", "Leg 2 ratio",value = "")),
        
        br(),
        
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg3position", "Leg 3 position:", choices = list("Buy", "Sell"))),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg3type", "Leg 3 type:", choices = list("Call", "Put", "Future"))),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg3price","Leg 3 price", value ="")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg3strike", "Leg 3 strike",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg3exp", "Leg 3 exp",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg3ratio", "Leg 3 ratio",value = "")),
        
        br(),
                
        div(HTML("<br>")),br(),
      ),
      
  
      
      conditionalPanel(
        
        
        condition = "input.strategy == 'STRADDLE SWAP'",
        
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg1position", "Leg 1 position:", choices = list("Buy", "Sell"))),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg1type", "Leg 1 type:", choices = list("Call", "Put", "Future"))),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg1price", "Leg 1 price",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg1strike", "Leg 1 strike",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg1exp", "Leg 1 exp",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg1ratio", "Leg 1 ratio",value = "")),
        
        br(),
        
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg2position", "Leg 2 position:", choices = list("Buy", "Sell"))),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg2type", "Leg 2 type:", choices = list("Call", "Put", "Future"))),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg2price","Leg 2 price", value ="")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg2strike", "Leg 2 strike",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg2exp", "Leg 2 exp",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg2ratio", "Leg 2 ratio",value = "")),
        
        br(),
        
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg3position", "Leg 3 position:", choices = list("Buy", "Sell"))),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg3type", "Leg 3 type:", choices = list("Call", "Put", "Future"))),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg3price","Leg 3 price", value ="")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg3strike", "Leg 3 strike",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg3exp", "Leg 3 exp",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg3ratio", "Leg 3 ratio",value = "")),
        
        br(),
        
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg4position", "Leg 4 position:", choices = list("Buy", "Sell"))),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",selectInput("Leg4type", "Leg 4 type:", choices = list("Call", "Put", "Future"))),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg4price","Leg 4 price", value ="")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg4strike", "Leg 4 strike",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg4exp", "Leg 4 exp",value = "")),
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg4ratio", "Leg 4 ratio",value = "")),
        
        br(),
        
        div(HTML("<br>")),br(),
      ),



) 

server <- function(input, output){



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, this piece of code in Rmarkdown does not work as the condition I am using is not the correct one. I also have tried  `is.null` and  `missing()`, do you have any suggestions?

The error that it is give is:

Warning: Error in eval: argument is missing, with no default
[No stack trace available]

Which is obvious and is exactly what I would like to check

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: @Limey I added the necessary code to allow you to run it, would you now be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have several issues.  Please post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the future.

1. Several typos, as you need to access with the `inputID`. It should be `input$Leg1price` and not `input$leg1price`.
2. `ID`s should be unique. You are using most IDs more than once.
3. The value of the `input$Leg1Price` is missing, as you have assigned it initially.
4. `legindex` should be assigned an object, such as a `reactive` object; not just a return statement.

Lastly, please check the logic as to what you define within the reactive object.

Try this

```
library(shiny) 

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("strategy", "Strategy:", choices = list("DIVIDEND FUTURE SPREAD","STRANGLE","BUTTERFLY","STRADDLE SWAP")),
  
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.strategy == 'DIVIDEND FUTURE SPREAD'||input.strategy == 'STRANGLE'",

          div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg1price", "Leg 1 price",value = "")),
          
          br(),
          
          div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg2price","Leg 2 price", value ="")),  
          br(),
          
          div(HTML("<br>")),br(),
          ),
      
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.strategy == 'BUTTERFLY'",

        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg21price", "Leg 1 price",value = "")),
        
        br(),
        
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg22price","Leg 2 price", value ="")),
        
        br(),
        
        div(style="display: inline-block; width: 75px;",textInput("Leg23price","Leg 3 price", value ="")),
        
        br(),
                
        div(HTML("<br>")),br(),
      )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  observe({
    legindex <- reactive(
      if(input$Leg1price=="") return("Leg 1 is NULL")
      # else if(is.null(input$Leg21price)) return("Leg 1:")
      # else if (is.null(input$Leg22price)) return(c("Leg 1:","Leg 2:"))
      else return(c("Leg 1:","Leg 2:","Leg 3:"))
    )
    print(legindex())
    print(input$Leg1price)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```